# Тире перед "нет"

Tags: пунктуация

У меня постоянно возникает вопрос, ставится ли тире перед "нет" в таких фразах, как, например, "Тебе нравится, а мне (-) нет". Есть какое-то правило по этому поводу?

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434035/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычное неполное предложение, а в неполном предложении при отсутствии паузы и интонационного подчеркивания тире можно не ставить