# Постановка тире перед "нет"

Tags: пунктуация

> На лекции одни студенты делали пометки в тетради, другие же (—) наоборот. 
>   *Или:* на лекции одни студенты делали пометки в тетради, другие же (—) нет.

Нужно ли тире в данных примерах? 
И ещё: в каких случаях в целом ставится тире перед "нет" и "да"?

Comment: Интересно, "наоборот"  - это как? Делали тетрадь в пометках?

Comment: Имеется в виду, что не делали

Comment: Alena, @Мимоходов шутит редко, но метко.

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7747/%d0%a2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**На лекции одни студенты делали пометки в тетради, другие же — нет.**

Из словаря: НЕТ, I. частица **Вместо сказ. с отриц., а также вместо словосоч. или целого предл. с отриц., когда они противопоставляются предыдущему.** Возник спор: одни утверждали, что нужно строить дорогу, другие - что нет. Она думала: придёт он или нет.

Таким образом, НЕТ заменяет словосочетание "не делали пометок в тетради".

В данном случае тире обозначает паузу в речи и обычно ставится, но не всегда (зависит от структуры предложения и желания автора).

Примеры

Одни представители группы впоследствии воспользовались этой возможностью, **другие нет.** Только посмотришь, и видно… одни растут и меняются, **другие нет**.

У каждого есть данные свои. Одни способны к этому, **другие ― нет.** Почему одни вещества реагируют между собой, а **другие ― нет**?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, тире здесь - это тот самый случай, когда "если нельзя, но надо, то можно".

Речь о том, что тире это очень хочется поставить для наглядности, но его никак нельзя признать обязательным.
Вот косвенное тому подтверждение. 
[Тире перед "нет"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7747)

Я перерыл гуглом изрядно источников - от академичекских, до совсем уж дидактически простецких (типа https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html) - нигде четко не сказано, что при данных условиях тире обязательно.

Всё дело в том, что тире, в отличие от всех остальных знаков, бывает *пунктуационным* (определяется синтаксисом или семантикой предложения) и *интонационным* (неожиданность, резкий поворот, но часто передает, однако, не интонацию, а просто ритм или период речи). 
Так вот первое, пунктуационное тире обязательно к использованию, второе - нет: например, практически любую фразу можно произнести и без паузы, а саму паузу, даже если автор точно знает, что она там есть, не обязательно как-то отмечать на письме.

Что мы имеем в исходном примере для обязательного тире? Пропущенное слово (эллипсис)? Нет. Присоединение сказуемого к подлежащему с помощью специального оборота? Тоже нет. Соединение двух существительных, одно в роли смыслового сказуемого (стиль лозунга типа "Миру - мир")? Тоже не похоже. Все остальное совсем уж далеко.

А вот интонационное может тире ставится почти что везде, если автор так видит ритмику речи. Период (в разных вариантах, например распадение на две параллельные по смыслу части) - только одно из рекомендательных условий, но даже его в нашем примере может и не увидеть.

Получается, что пауза - единственное основание для тире. 
Но такое тире никогда не будет обязательным.

Поэтому, отвечая на вопрос "**Нужно** ли тут тире?", скажу так.

***Тире вполне возможно, но не обязательно.***   По-другому сформулировать, не впадая в ошибку, будет трудно.

Comment: Благодарю за полезную информацию!

Answer (score 1):

Правил, объясняющих постановку тире, - море, я выбрала  самое вкусное:

> Для выражения неожиданности может отделяться посредством тире любая
>   часть предложения, например:
>
> И щуку бросили — в реку (Крылов). И съела бедного певца — до крошки
>   (он же).
>
> ---

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire) - всё-превсё о тире.

[Тире между членами предложения.](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827474.html)

В двух приведённых предложениях можно пойти по совсем простому пути:

> Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного
>   предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое)
>   восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска
>   делается пауза.

Comment: Какое сказуемое тут можно восстановить? Чем является "нет" в данном предложении?

Comment: Спасибо большое!